# Отсортировать отделы и должности

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework

Предположим, есть такая БД:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно создать коллекцию `Dictionary`, где в роли `key` будет `отдел`, а в роли `value` — `должность`?

Вот скриншот того, чего пытаюсь добиться:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То есть, нужно как-то отсортировать.

Что я пытался сделать:

```
public class MultiDictionary
{
    public static Dictionary<string, List<string>> MyDict = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();

    public static void AddEx(string department, string post)
    {
        var listPost = new List<string> { post };

        if (MyDict.ContainsKey(department))
        {
            MyDict[department].Add(post);
        }
        else
        {
            MyDict.Add(department, listPost);
        }
    }
}

MultiDictionary.AddEx("Руководители", "Зам....");
```

И это работает для меня, но не в случае с загрузкой из БД, т.к отдел и должность это две разные модели.

Вот такой код:

```
foreach(var depart in Department.DisplayName())
{
    foreach(var post in Post.DisplayName())
    {
        MultiDictionary.AddEx(depart, post);
    }
}
```

но из-за того, что у меня цикл в цикле, получается каша. А как по другому выполнить `AddEx`?
В общем, подскажите, пожалуйста, как грамотно это можно реализовать? А то меня что-то не в ту степь понесло.

UPD:

Модель:

```
[Table("employees")]
public class Employees
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Отдел")]
    public string Department { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Должность")]
    public string Post { get; set; }

    public Employees() { }
    public Employees(string department, string post)
    {
        Department = department;
        Post = post;
    }
    
    public static void AddEmployees(Employees employees)
    {
        Singlet.db.Employees.Add(employees);
        Singlet.db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Контекст:

```
public class ApplicationContext : DbContext
{
    public ApplicationContext() : base("DBConnection") { }
    public DbSet<Employees> Employees { get; set; }
}
```

Заполнение данными:

```
var employees = new Employees()
{
    Department = "Руководители",
    Post = "Директор"
};
Employees.AddEmployees(employees);
```

Comment: Если бы вы привели код моделей, контекста и код заполнения данными, то ответ получили бы в течение нескольких минут.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, обновил пост.

Comment: Ничё не понял... На схеме у вас одна таблица Employees с двумя колонками Отделы и Должности. / В коде две таблицы. Никак не связанные между собой.

Comment: Синглтон, статические методы... Ну как тут обойтись без мата?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, блин, извиняюсь, я напутал всё. Сейчас исправлю.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, обновил пост. p.s: а что, использование синглтон, стат.методов совсем плохо, да?)

Comment: Как минимум, использование статики негативно отражается на вашей памяти. Создайте экземпляр класса и передавайте его можно другими классами, делайте там что угодно с ним. К чему эта статика? Неужто без неё не обойтись? Касаемо синглтона, читал даже где-то, что его за паттерн полноценный не считают. Никогда его в жизни не использовал и не планирую. Если тонна более красивых и полезных паттернов. Возвращаясь к вашей задаче, само хранение в словаре выглядит крайне странно. Начну с класса Employees (почему множественное число...). Класс - один конкретный объект. Не коллекция объектов, а один...

Comment: ...один конкретный. Далее, давайте определимся, каким свойства имеет сотрудник: Имя, департамент и отдел. Можем ли мы "Департамент" и "Должность" выделить в отдельные классы и хранить их в Employees не в типе string, а в классе? `public Deparment Deparment {get;set;}` (пример). У нас уже начинает вырисовываться некая иерархия. Не хватает только добавить к этому всему уникальный какой-нибудь идентификатор, с помощью которого можно было-бы их отличать между собой в БД. Для этого отлично подходит тип int или guid. Формировать можно как на стороне клиента, так и на стороне сервера. Выбор за вами

Comment: Возвращаясь к теме вопроса, предлагаю изменить ваше хранение данных: Создать 2 словаря: Dictionary<Guid, Employee>, Dictionary<Guid, Deparment>, Dictionary<Guid, Position>. Для получения данных вы должны обратиться к Values нужного словаря. Сортировать можно с помощью OrderBy (using LInq). Советую для данных операций выделить отдельный метод, который-бы возвращал IEnumarable<T>, где T - наш класс.

Comment: Через минут 30 постараюсь оформить в виде ответа. Сейчас немного занят

Comment: @Максим Посмотрите ответ. Если появятся вопросы - оставляйте их под ответом. Постарался затронуть сразу все аспекты и привести пример реализации, в которой можно легко обойтись без статики и прочего

Comment: Ваш способ с синглтоном плох хотя бы потому, что `DbContext` не является потокобезопасным. А рано или поздно вы придёте к использованию потоков/тасков. Тогда-то ваш код и посыпется. Рано или поздно вы придёте к использованию асинхронности. А ваши статические методы синхронные... В общем, придётся всё переписывать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Имеем сущность:

```
public class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Department { get; set; }
    public string Post { get; set; }
}
```

Имеем контекст:

```
public class ApplicationContext : DbContext
{
    // ...
    
    public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}
```

Создаём БД и заполняем таблицу данными:

```
using var db = new ApplicationContext();
db.Database.EnsureDeleted();
db.Database.EnsureCreated();

db.Employees.Add(new Employee { Department = "Руководители", Post = "Генеральный директор" });
db.Employees.Add(new Employee { Department = "Руководители", Post = "Зам. генерального директора" });
db.Employees.Add(new Employee { Department = "Центр питания", Post = "Повар" });
db.Employees.Add(new Employee { Department = "Центр питания", Post = "Помощник повара" });
db.Employees.Add(new Employee { Department = "Руководители", Post = "Главный бухгалтер" });

db.SaveChanges();
```

Теперь одним запросом получаем данные в необходимом виде:

```
using var db = new ApplicationContext();

var dict = db.Employees
    .GroupBy(e => e.Department, e => e.Post)
    .Select(g => new { g.Key, List = g.ToList() })
    .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.List);

foreach (var pair in dict)
    Console.WriteLine(pair.Key + ": " + string.Join(", ", pair.Value));
```

---

Рассмотрим, как может выглядеть вариант, когда для отделов и должностей существуют отдельные таблицы.

Имеем сущности:

```
public class Department
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class Post
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Department Department { get; set; }
    public Post Post { get; set; }
}
```

Имеем контекст:

```
public class ApplicationContext : DbContext
{
    // ...

    public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Department> Departments { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}
```

В данном случае таблица Employees связана с таблицами Departments и Posts связями один-к-одному (one-to-one).

Создаём БД и заполняем таблицы отделов и должностей:

```
using var db = new ApplicationContext();
db.Database.EnsureDeleted();
db.Database.EnsureCreated();

var department1 = new Department { Name = "Руководители" };
var department2 = new Department { Name = "Центр питания" };

db.Departments.Add(department1);
db.Departments.Add(department2);

var post1 = new Post { Name = "Генеральный директор" };
var post2 = new Post { Name = "Зам. генерального директора" };
var post3 = new Post { Name = "Повар" };
var post4 = new Post { Name = "Помощник повара" };
var post5 = new Post { Name = "Главный бухгалтер" };

db.Posts.AddRange(post1, post2, post3, post4, post5);

db.SaveChanges();
```

Теперь, когда мы хотим добавить работника, мы сперва должны получить из БД записи должности и отдела для него.
После чего создаём сотрудников, назначаем им нужные свойства и сохраняем в БД.

```
using var db = new ApplicationContext();

var managersDepartment = db.Departments.First(d => d.Name == "Руководители");
var nutritionCenterDepartment = db.Departments.First(d => d.Name == "Центр питания");

var ceoPost = db.Posts.First(p => p.Name == "Генеральный директор");
var deputyCeofPost = db.Posts.First(p => p.Name == "Зам. генерального директора");
var chefPost = db.Posts.First(p => p.Name == "Повар");
var cookfPost = db.Posts.First(p => p.Name == "Помощник повара");
var chiefAccountantPost = db.Posts.First(p => p.Name == "Главный бухгалтер");

var employee1 = new Employee { Department = managersDepartment, Post = ceoPost, Name = "Вася" };
var employee2 = new Employee { Department = managersDepartment, Post = deputyCeofPost, Name = "Петя" };
var employee3 = new Employee { Department = nutritionCenterDepartment, Post = chefPost, Name = "Джон Сильвер" };
var employee4 = new Employee { Department = nutritionCenterDepartment, Post = cookfPost, Name = "Реми" };
var employee5 = new Employee { Department = managersDepartment, Post = chiefAccountantPost, Name = "Изольда Паллна" };

db.Employees.AddRange(employee1, employee2, employee3, employee4, employee5);
db.SaveChanges();
```

Запрос на получение сгруппированных по отделам должностей будет практически такой же, как и раньше. Только нужно брать названия `Name`.

```
using var db = new ApplicationContext();

var dict = db.Employees
    .GroupBy(e => e.Department.Name, e => e.Post.Name)
    .Select(g => new { g.Key, List = g.ToList() })
    .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.List);

foreach (var pair in dict)
    Console.WriteLine(pair.Key + ": " + string.Join(", ", pair.Value));
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Но есть ещё вопрос. В случае, если, например, `отдел` в одной таблице — `table1`, а `должность` в другой — `table2`, можно как-то также получить словарь?

Comment: извиняюсь за долгий ответ, ваш пример очень помог мне. Большое спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Первое, что хотелось-бы отметить - используйте для каждой записи какое-то уникальное значение. Как я писал выше в комментариях, можно использовать как простой тип int, так и Guid. Представьте, что это число - ссылка на объект. Таким образом, например, EmployeeData (таблица в БД) будет выглядеть следующим образом:

```
[Table("EmployeeData")]
internal class EmployeeData
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Имя")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Отдел")]
    public Guid DepartmentId { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Должность")]
    public Guid PositionId { get; set; }

    public EmployeeData(Guid id, string name, Guid deparmentId, Guid positiionId)
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
        DepartmentId = deparmentId;
        PositionId = positiionId;
    }

    protected EmployeeData() { }
}
```

По аналогии создаём DepartmentData (свойства Guid Id, string Name) и PositionData (свойства Guid Id, string Name).

DepartmentData:

```
[Table("DepartmentData")]
internal class DepartmentData
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Название отдела")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public DepartmentData(Guid id, string name)
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
    }

    protected DepartmentData() { }
}
```

PositionData:

```
[Table("PositionData")]
internal class PositionData
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Название должности")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public PositionData(Guid id, string name)
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
    }

    protected PositionData() { }
}
```

Но дело в том, что пользоваться такими данными - не очень удобно. Давайте представим их в виде моделей, с которыми будет в дальнейшем работать.

Employee:

```
internal class Employee
{
    public Guid Id { get; private set; }

    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public Department Department { get; private set; }

    public Position Position { get; private set; }

    public Employee(Guid id, string name, Department department, Position position)
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
        Department = department;
        Position = position;
    }

    protected Employee() { }
}
```

Department:

```
internal class Department
{
    public Guid Id { get; private set; }

    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public Department(Guid id, string name)
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
    }

    protected Department() { }
}
```

Position:

```
internal class Position
{
    public Guid Id { get; private set; }

    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public Position(Guid id, string name)
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
    }

    protected Position() { }
}
```

Но в чём загвостка - нам нужно конвертировать из одного типа в другой. В этом нам поможет Factory. Она позволит избежать большого количества повторений кода. В дальнейшем нужно будет лишь воспользоваться ею, чтоб конвертировать что-либо из одного типа в другой. К примеру, если у вас есть коллекция `IEnumerable<DepartmentData>`, которую нужно конвертировать в IEnumerable<Department`- вам нужно написать нечто подобное:`depatmentData.Select(x => DepartmentFactory.Create(x));`.

DeparmentFactory:

```
internal static class DeparmentFactory
{
    public static Department Create(DepartmentData department) =>
        new(department.Id, department.Name);

    public static DepartmentData CreateData(Department department) =>
        new(department.Id, department.Name);
}
```

PositionFactory:

```
internal class PositionFactory
{
    public static Position Create(PositionData position) =>
        new(position.Id, position.Name);

    public static PositionData CreateData(Position position) =>
        new(position.Id, position.Name);
}
```

Дело с EmployeeFactory чуть сложнее - нам нужно в нашей базе или в кэше (речь о нём дальше) найти данные по их Id. Из-за этого добавим 2 дополнительных параметра.

```
internal static class EmployeeFactory
{
    public static Employee Create(EmployeeData employee, Department department, Position position) =>
        new(employee.Id, employee.Name, department, position);

    public static EmployeeData CreateData(Employee employee) =>
        new(employee.Id, employee.Name, employee.Department.Id, employee.Position.Id);
}
```

Далее необходимо определиться, где наши данные будут храниться. Реализаций очень много. Я выбрал наиболее простую и понятную - кэш. Итак, создадим общий интерфейс, от которого будут наследоваться все остальные наши кэши (вообще, интерфейсы много где можно создать для упрощения своей жизни в будущем - для factory, например):

```
internal interface IBaseCache<T>
{
    public IReadOnlyList<T> Values { get; }

    public T GetById(Guid id);

    public void Add(T entity);

    public bool TryAdd(T entity);

    public bool Remove(Guid id);
}
```

Далее создадим классы, в которых будем хранить кэш наших сотрудников и тд:

EmployeesCache:

```
internal sealed class EmployeesCache : IBaseCache<Employee>
{
    private readonly Dictionary<Guid, Employee> _employees;

    public IReadOnlyList<Employee> Values => _employees.Values.ToList();

    public void Add(Employee entity) =>
        _employees.Add(entity.Id, entity);

    public bool TryAdd(Employee entity) =>
        _employees.TryAdd(entity.Id, entity);

    public Employee GetById(Guid id) =>
        _employees.TryGetValue(id, out var employee) is true
            ? employee
            : throw new KeyNotFoundException(nameof(id));

    public bool Remove(Guid id) =>
        _employees.Remove(id);
}
```

DepartmentCache:

```
internal sealed class DepartmentCache : IBaseCache<Department>
{
    private readonly Dictionary<Guid, Department> _demartments;

    public IReadOnlyList<Department> Values => _demartments.Values.ToList();

    public void Add(Department entity) =>
        _demartments.Add(entity.Id, entity);

    public bool TryAdd(Department entity) =>
        _demartments.TryAdd(entity.Id, entity);

    public Department GetById(Guid id) =>
        _demartments.TryGetValue(id, out var department) is true
            ? department
            : throw new KeyNotFoundException(nameof(id));

    public bool Remove(Guid id) =>
        _demartments.Remove(id);
}
```

PositionCache:

```
internal sealed class PositionCache : IBaseCache<Position>
{
    private readonly Dictionary<Guid, Position> _positions;

    public IReadOnlyList<Position> Values => _positions.Values.ToList();

    public void Add(Position entity) =>
        _positions.Add(entity.Id, entity);

    public bool TryAdd(Position entity) =>
        _positions.TryAdd(entity.Id, entity);

    public Position GetById(Guid id) =>
        _positions.TryGetValue(id, out var position) is true
            ? position
            : throw new KeyNotFoundException(nameof(id));

    public bool Remove(Guid id) =>
        _positions.Remove(id);
}
```

Далее создадим некоторые контроллеры, которые будут помогать нам взаимодействовать с кэшем. Я реализую всего-лишь один. Остальные можно сделать по аналогии:

```
internal class EmployeeController
{
    public EmployeesCache EmployeesCache { get; }

    public EmployeeController(EmployeesCache employeesCache)
    {
        EmployeesCache = employeesCache;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Employee> GetEmployeesByDepartmentId(Guid departmentId) =>
        EmployeesCache.Values.Where(x => x.Department.Id.Equals(departmentId));
}
```

Для контроллер - некоторое расширение вашего кэше, которое позволяет взаимодействовать с ним.

Таким образом, с помощью контроллера мы можем как-либо отредактировать данные в нашем кэше (Пример: `EmployeesCache.Add(....)`). Так же, мы можем прописать тут необходимые методы для сортировки и прочего. Такая реализация позволит структурировать нашу программу и сделать его понятной для будущего Васи, который будет копаться в вашем коде

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ, только для меня это пока выглядит как-то сложно. Буду разбираться. Спасибо.